# How to set the repository domain policy so a Gradle-based Build pipeline can access AWS CodeArtifact?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codeartifact

I've configured an AWSCodeArtifact repository which I understand is normally added to Gradle builds in this form:

```
maven {
    url '<REDACTED>'
    credentials {
        username "aws"
        password System.env.CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN
    }
}
```

It's building on my machine and indeed accessing the libraries through the configured repository rather than Maven Central.

Now I want to configure a build project and pipeline that will do the same thing for CI/CD purposes, but I seem to be missing something:

- I've added this policy to the repository

  ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                  "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<REDACTED>:role/service-role/<REDACTED>"
              },
              "Action": "codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken",
              "Resource": "*"
          }
       ]
   }
  ```
- In my Buildspec, I've added this line:

  ```
   export CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN=`aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain <REDACTED> --query authorizationToken --output text`
  ```

However, this doesn't have the desired effect. My build log shows:

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:sts::<REDACTED>:assumed-role/codebuild-<REDACTED>-service-role/AWSCodeBuild-e8c8232b-a0b0-4909-ab2b-12737c90f2bd is not authorized to perform: codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: arn:aws:codeartifact:<REDACTED>:<REDACTED>:domain/<REDACTED> because no identity-based policy allows the codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken action
```

What am I missing?